# What is #' I see in Ring app?

Tags: clojure, ring

Example code:

```
(def app
  (-> #'handler
     (ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace)
     (wrap-spy)))
```

I'm not Clojure expert and this `#'` baffles me -- what is that?

Comment: To lookup things like this you may use [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%23%27)

Comment: It is a [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) for [var](http://clojure.org/vars)-quote.

Comment: It is really close to the duplicates mentioned.  The one difference is that it's asking about ring in particular, which is probably how a lot of people first encounter `#'`.  The "ring" keyword (and tag) might make this worth keeping around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [reader macro called var-quote](http://clojure.org/reader#toc2).  `#'x` is the same as `(var x)`.

What it does is give you a reference to the *variable* called `x`, and not the *value* referred to by `x`.  In this case you're saying to ring, "the function to call is in `handler`" rather than "here's the function to call."  This means you can update (redefine in repl) the definition of `handler` and ring will find it, even if you don't update the rest of the app.